# Remove everything except specific part of string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that ends with a version number, which could have two or three version parts.

```
SOMEPREFIX10.1.1
```

or

```
SOMEPREFIX11.2
```

I would like to remove the prefix of the version number but in a generic way.

I can do something like this

```
$result =~ s/SOMEPREFIX//
```

This works, but if the `SOMEPREFIX` changes I need to modify the regex pattern.

How could I remove everything except what matches the version number (I guess `(\d+\.(\d.)?\d)`?)

Comment: What about... `s/^\D+//`?

Comment: @MattJacob:Won't that remove `.` too?

Comment: Does the version ever start with a dot?

Comment: @MattJacob:Ah I understand now. Yes it does not

Comment: But `SOMEPREFIX10.1.1` has a version number with four digits. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Borodin:My bad. I mean 2 or 3 components. I corrected post. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very imprecise, but it sounds like you just need to capture all decimal digits and dots at the end of the string

```
if ( my ($version) = /([\d.]+)$/ ) {

    # use $version
}
```

Comment: How is that different from `s/^\D+//`? I mean seems to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string starts with only alphabets and ends with version number, below script will work for you.

Below script worked for below strings

```
SOMEPREFIX10.1.1 
SOMEPREFIXajdgcjhadjh134.1.1 
SOMEPREFIX11.2 
SOMEPREFIXajdgcjhadjh134.1.1.657.34.5
```

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @reg=qw(SOMEPREFIX10.1.1 SOMEPREFIXajdgcjhadjh134.1.1 SOMEPREFIX11.2 SOMEPREFIXajdgcjhadjh134.1.1.657.34.5);

foreach (@reg)
{
        $_=~ /([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)/;

        print "$2\n";
}
```

output:

```
10.1.1
134.1.1
11.2
134.1.1.657.34.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to match two or three octet numbers at the end of the string, and if you get them, remove everything else in the string?

Right.

```
s/.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2})$/$1/
```

I'm figuring you know when and how to use the `=~` operator.

Answer (score -1):

If SOMEPREFIX include some number you whould match until the first combination of numbers and dot without match it than you could use positive lookahead like:

```
my $result = 'SOME3PREFIX11.1.0';
$result =~  s/^.*?(?=(\d+\.))//;

print $result;

__DATA__
11.1.0
```